# flutter error on modal bottom sheet Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter

I am trying to code a modal bottom sheet with a stream list inside.The list can be scrollable but I continuing having this error: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code

```
  _showModal(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                Text('Select event',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium)
              ]),
              ListView.builder(
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: widget.user.myEvents!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (contex, index) {
                    return StreamBuilder(
                        stream: di
                            .gt<GetSingleEventUseCase>()
                            .call(widget.user.myEvents![index]),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return TileSettings(
                                title: snapshot.data!.first.eventName!,
                                leading: snapshot.data!.first.guestsid!
                                            .contains(widget.otherUser.uid) ||
                                        snapshot.data!.first.guestsid!
                                            .contains(widget.otherUser.uid)
                                    ? const Image(image: ticketLinear)
                                    : const Image(image: ticket),
                                onTap: () {},
                                trailing: const SizedBox.shrink());
                          } else {
                            return TileSettings(
                                title: 'No events',
                                leading: const Image(image: cross),
                                onTap: () {},
                                trailing: const SizedBox.shrink());
                          }
                        });
                  })
            ])));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrap Column with Container and give maxHeight in constrains.

```
       _showModal(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Container(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 250),
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  Text('Select event',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium)
                ]),
                ListView.builder(
                    physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: widget.user.myEvents!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (contex, index) {
                      return StreamBuilder(
                          stream: di
                              .gt<GetSingleEventUseCase>()
                              .call(widget.user.myEvents![index]),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              return TileSettings(
                                  title: snapshot.data!.first.eventName!,
                                  leading: snapshot.data!.first.guestsid!
                                              .contains(widget.otherUser.uid) ||
                                          snapshot.data!.first.guestsid!
                                              .contains(widget.otherUser.uid)
                                      ? const Image(image: ticketLinear)
                                      : const Image(image: ticket),
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  trailing: const SizedBox.shrink());
                            } else {
                              return TileSettings(
                                  title: 'No events',
                                  leading: const Image(image: cross),
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  trailing: const SizedBox.shrink());
                            }
                          });
                    })
              ]),
            )));
  }
```